# How to delete elements from deque based on some condition?

Tags: python

I know how to remove elements from a list while iteration. What about similar operation in deque? In the following example, 'my_deque' is a deque.

```
 for event in my_deque.copy():
     if event in event_sets:
        remove event from my_deque
```

Is there some way to do this? Can deque only push and pop from two ends?

Comment: `deque` has a ['remove' method](https://pythontic.com/containers/deque/remove).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if I understand your question, but if you want to remove the first occurrence of x in a deque you could use the function `my_deque.remove(x)`

```py
from collections import deque

my_deque = deque([1,2,3,4,5,6])

for event in my_deque.copy():
     if event in [2,4,5]:
        my_deque.remove(event)

print(my_deque)

# deque([1, 3, 6])
```

I hope you could find this useful!